# Dividing Point Cloud into voxels

Tags: computational-geometry, computer-vision

I am reading a paper on implementing convolution neural network for a 3D point cloud. In this paper, they are dividing the point cloud into voxels. Is there any easy way to do it using point cloud library?

Comment: What do you mean by "dividing the point cloud into voxels"?

Comment: By "dividing the point cloud into voxels", you mean you want to voxelize your point cloud? If yes, your point cloud represents a closed manifold or not?